# Frame navigation issue on Back button in Drawer Layout Windows Phone 8.1(Universal) WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, winrt-xaml

I want to use drawer layout in my app for hamburger but since my app have more than 30 pages having the drawer template declared on each page is not feasible hence I wanted to have the drawer layout as master page with a child/content page inside for which I have written below code with frame tag to navigate to page on click of menu in drawer layout.

Below is my XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="Rootlayout">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!-- title bar-->
    <Grid x:Name="TitleBar" Height="50" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="SkyBlue">
        <Image  Source="/Assets/fs-logo.png" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
    </Grid>
    <!--Drawer Layout-->
    <drawer:DrawerLayout x:Name="DrawerLayout" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <Grid>
            <Frame x:Name="contentFrame" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="listFragment" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" >
            <ListView x:Name="listItem" SelectionChanged="listItem_SelectionChanged">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="20" Foreground="Black" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>      
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </drawer:DrawerLayout>
</Grid>
```

While the behavior is exactly as I want but there is problem with hardware back button as when it's pressed the application gets exit. Even I have handle back button press event using following code is app.xaml.cs

```
//Below code of line in app constructor & it's method defination
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
#endif

#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP    
void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, Windows.Phone.UI.Input.BackPressedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    if (frame != null && frame.CanGoBack)
        {
            frame.GoBack();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
}
#endif
```

Can anyone help me how to resolve this issue of back button or is there any other way i can utilize drawer layout by which I don't have to write the drawer layout xaml code on each page. One way is using usercontrol but since the content grid is part of drawerlayout I'm not able to figure out how to club my usercontrol & my normal page xaml. Please help thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are checking `CanGoBack` on the wrong frame.

The `Window.Current.Content` is your base frame containing the DrawerLayout. What you actually want to address is the `contentFrame` inside of it.

So what you really want to look at is:

```
(Window.Current.Content as RootPage)?.Frame.CanGoBack
```

Where `RootPage` is the name of your Page for the Xaml you posted in your question.

Comment: Thanx I'll try the same. Also would like to know is this the right approach to use drawerlayout or making a drawerlayout user control is more preferable & if yes how can I do the same.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Depends on your project and requirements.

Comment: This doesn't work as Page doesn't have CanGoBack & GoBack()

Comment: Ah, missed the *.Frame" ^^